# Solr search suggestion and results on wrong spelling

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

I am using solr 4.8.1 with django haystack and indexing across multiple fields - I am seeing a problem with some search queries that are spelt wrong, they are coming up with matches and also being put forward as a spelling suggestion.

Example: I have indexed documents that contain the word 'Berkeley' if I use the Solr admin UI and search for 'berkele' it comes up with the spelling suggestion 'berkelei' and then if i query 'berkelei' it will return 429 results (the same amount if I query 'berkeley')

I am using the example solrconfig.xml that came with solr and just generating the schema.xml using django haystack - has anyone got an idea why this would happen?

Basically I would like it to give the correct spelling suggestion when I query something like 'berkele' rather than another misspelt word

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by removing  from the schema.xml file generated by django-haystack.